# Insert error: Rowid always 1

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, rowid

When I try to insert in my SQLite database, no error message is thrown. My problem is, that it seems that nothing is written in it, rowid always stays 1. When I select out of this table, the size of the `cursor` is 0.

I´m sure that `ename`, `ezeit`, `egenaueres` have values.

Here is my insert function:

```
public void insertereignis(String ename, String ezeit, String egenaueres){
    long rowId = -1;
    try{    
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        System.out.println(ename + ezeit + egenaueres);
        cv.put(EREIGNISNAME, ename);
        cv.put(EREIGNISZEIT, ezeit);
        cv.put(EREIGNISGENAUERES, egenaueres);

        rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_EREIGNIS, null, cv);
        db.endTransaction();

        selectEreignis();

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "insert() Ereignis", e);
    }
    finally{
        Log.d(TAG, "insert(): Ereignis rowId=" + rowId);
    }
```

Here is my select function that gets 0 for cursor size:

```
public Cursor selectEreignis(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_EREIGNIS, new String[] {"ereignisname", "ereigniszeit", "ereignisgenaueres"}, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
        db.endTransaction();
        System.out.println("HALLLIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII"  + cursor.getCount());
        return cursor;
    }
```

The table looks like this:

```
private static final String TABLE_EREIGNIS_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_EREIGNIS + " (" + ereignisid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + EREIGNISNAME + " TEXT, " + EREIGNISZEIT + " TEXT, " + EREIGNISGENAUERES + " TEXT, " + KINDID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (" + KINDID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME_Kind + "(" + id + "));";
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the problem. Using  `db.beginTransaction();` and `db.endTransaction();` was my problem. Deleted this lines and everything works fine.